# Java String.join and tabs

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to split a string using a delimiter, do operations on the elements than join together again using the same delimiter.

```
String[] split = input.split(deli); // split on the string
// Do stuff with split
return String.join(delimiter,split); // join with the same string
```

This works fine, unless the used deli is '\t' (tab) (and probably other similar ones).
Because String.join refers to the delimiter as a 'charsequence' might this be the cause?

For example:

```
 var deli="\t";
 var split = data.split(deli); // splits properly
 var join = String.join(deli,split); // joins with sequence instead of char 
 var it = join.split(deli); // doesn't work
```

Is this normal? If so, how can I best work around it?
For now i'm doing this.

```
var deli="\t";
var split = data.split(deli); // splits properly
if( deli.equalsIgnoreCase("\\t")) 
     return String.join(String.valueOf((char)9),items);
return String.join(deli,items);
```

Delimiter is read from a xml file attribute and that was read as "\\t" and not "\t" (in ide debug it showed as \t). Which is to be expected but because the split always worked, never thought anything of it.

```
// First split works, second doesn't
    var input ="[2023-04-25 07:31:26.175]\t1\tgeneric:qsr2150|par\t1770.112, 10.25, 9.043";
    var deli = "\\t";
    String[] split = input.split(deli); // splits properly
    var join = String.join(deli,split);
    var split2 = join.split(deli); // doesn't split

// Both splits work
    var input ="[2023-04-25 07:31:26.175]\t1\tgeneric:qsr2150|par\t1770.112, 10.25, 9.043";
    var deli = "\t";
    String[] split = input.split(deli);
    var join = String.join(deli,split);
    var split2 = join.split(deli); // splits properly
```

So solution to my issue is properly converting \t attribute to a 'tab'.

But why does the first split work but not the second one? You'd expect to fail on the first split.

Comment: What do you mean about *doesn't work*? Add a string as an example and the expected output.

Comment: I know that it doesn't make sense, that's why I asked here. I found a way to fix it , but still not sure why it worked partially at all.

Comment: Context is everything. `String#split(String regex)` splits based on a regex.

Comment: But isn't it odd that using regex "\t" and "\\t" have the same result?

Comment: @Craio not really; regular expressions match their content literally, unless the character is a meta character. A tab will be matched literally, while `\t` is a meta "character" which also matches a tab.

Comment: @knittl Ok, so as regex those two are the same, but for the join they aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context is everything.

- `"\t"` is a String with a single tab <kbd>⇥</kbd> character
- `"\\t"` is a String with a backslash character and a lower case 't' character
- `"\t"` is a regular expression which contains the literal tab character, which matches tab characters in the input
- `"\\t"` is a regular expression which contains the meta character `\t`, which matches tab characters in the input
- `"\\\\t"` is a string containing 2 backslashes and lower case 't' character. You can get it by executing `Pattern.quote("\\t")`.
- `"\\\\t"` is a regular expression which contains an escaped backslash and a lower case 't' (`\\t`), which matches a backslash followed by a lower case 't'.

The important thing to note is that [`String#split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) splits based on a *regex*:

> Splits this string around matches of the given [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

```
var input ="a\tb\tc"; // an 'a', a tab, a 'b', a tab, a 'c'
var deli = "\\t"; // a backslash and a 't'
String[] split = input.split(deli); // splits on the regex `\t`
var join = String.join(deli,split); // joins with backslash and t
// the value of join is now "a\\tb\\tc" (an 'a', a backslash, a 't', a 'b', a backslash, a 't', a 'c'
var split2 = join.split(deli); // the string does not contain any tabs anymore, so the regex matching tabs cannot split
```

You should be able to easily see the difference if you output the value of the variable `join` and `input` and comparing them.

Comment: As a side note, if we are not sure if out delimiter can be *interpreted* by regex and we want to be sure that regex will treat it *literally* we can use `Pattern.quote` to generate regex matching only such literal. So if we want to split on ``\`` followed by ``t`` we can write `split("\\\\t")` or `split(Pattern.quote("\\t"))`.In other words instead of `split(delimiter)` we can use `split(Pattern.quote(delimiter))`

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, I have extended my answer to clarify this